# Displaying Many to Many Relationship in MVC view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

I am creating a database driven application in MVC, my application is a "data dictionary" which shows reports and what Database tables are used in those reports. I am using a database first approach for MVC.

My database structure is as follows

```
*tblReport*
fldReportID
fldReportName
fldReportPurpose
fldOriginalSignOffDate

*tblDBTables*
fldTableID
fldTableName

*tblDBTablesUsed*
fldDBTablesUsedID
fldReportID
fldTableID
```

tblDBTablesUsed is the many-to-many link table IE each report has many tables and each table can be used in many reports.

i want to create a view page in MVC which displays the basic report information (held in tblReport) and also the information about the tables used in that report.

I have created a model for each table as follows:

```
public partial class tblReport
{

    public int fldReportID { get; set; }
    public string fldReportName { get; set; }
    public string fldReportPurpose { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> fldOriginalSignOffDate { get; set; }

}


public partial class tblDBTable
{

    public int fldTableID { get; set; }
    public string fldTableName { get; set; }

}

public partial class tblDBTablesUsed
{
    public int fldTablesUsedID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> fldReportID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> fldTableID { get; set; }

    public virtual tblDBTable tblDBTable { get; set; }
    public virtual tblReport tblReport { get; set; }
}
```

and my Dbcontext class:

```
public partial class DataDictionaryEntities : DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<tblDBTable> tblDBTables { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tblDBTablesUsed> tblDBTablesUseds { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tblReport> tblReports { get; set; }

}
```

I've created a viewmodel to hold the two entities I want to display in the view:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{

    public tblReport report = new tblReport();
    public IEnumerable<tblDBTable> dbtables;

}
```

and finally, in my reports controller, I have created the details action method

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {

        ReportViewModel rvm = new ReportViewModel();

        tblReport Report = db.tblReports.Find(id);

        //here we have an Ienumerable of the link table which gives us the table ID's used in this report
        IEnumerable<tblDBTablesUsed> DBTablesUsed = db.tblDBTablesUseds.Where(x => x.fldReportID == Report.fldReportID);


        //how to get the tables!?
        //DBTables = ??

        rvm.report = Report;
        rvm.dbtables = DBTables;

        return View(rvm);
    }
```

I am struggling to get the relevant tables- IEnumerable DBTablesUsed holds their IDs, but how do I get the records with those IDS from tblReport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Camilo.

i have managed to get the solution:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {

        ReportViewModel rvm = new ReportViewModel();

        tblReport report = db.tblReports.Find(id);
        List<tblDBTable> tablesinreport = new List<tblDBTable>();

        // get tables used in this report
        IQueryable<tblDBTable> ReportTables = from t1 in db.tblDBTablesUseds
                                              join t2 in db.tblDBTables on t1.fldTableID equals t2.fldTableID
                                              where t1.fldReportID == id
                                              select t2;
        tablesinreport= ReportTables.ToList();


        rvm.report = report;
        rvm.dbtables = tablesinreport;

        return View(rvm);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to get all children of the many-to-many helper table.
What you can do to achieve that is get all tblDBTablesUsed and use them to get the tblDBTable and tblReports using .Contains().

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
     ReportViewModel rvm = new ReportViewModel();
     tblReport Report = db.tblReports.Find(id);
     List<tblDBTablesUsed> DBTablesUsed = db.tblDBTablesUseds
         .Where(x => x.fldReportID == Report.fldReportID).ToList(); //execute DB query using ToList()

     List<tblReport> reports = db.tblReports
         .Where(rep => DBTablesUsed.Select(x => x.fldReportID).Contains(rep.fldReportID))
         .ToList();
     List<tblDBTable> tables= db.tblDBTables
         .Where(rep => DBTablesUsed.Select(x => x.fldTableName).Contains(rep.fldTableName))
         .ToList(); 

     rvm.report = reports;
     rvm.dbtables = tables;

     return View(rvm);
}
```

By the way, you have horrible naming conventions and you don't follow any c# naming style, which makes your code hard to read.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am getting 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument type of 'bool' could be found

Comment: If I change to            List<tblReport> reports = db.tblReports
                .Where(rep => DBTablesUsed.Select(x => x.fldReportID).Contains(rep.fldReportID))
                .ToList();

Comment: then I get An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'DatabaseFirst.Models.tblDBTablesUsed'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Sorry for multiple comments, first time posting on this site and having a few problems!

Comment: @stevee1986 Please post your code to a public repository and I will probably be able to help you better. The code I posted was done here so I cannot check its correctness

Comment: [link]https://dotnetfiddle.net/VjI5BB

I have commented where the errors are plus some other comments / questions

Thanks

Comment: @stevee1986 I have edited my code. I forgot to add a closing parenthesis after the .Contains() in both cases

Comment: Thanks,
Although now I am getting an error at runtime


Unable to create a constant value of type 'DatabaseFirst.Models.tblDBTablesUsed'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. 


Line 68:             .Where(x => x.fldReportID == Report.fldReportID).ToList(); //execute DB query using ToList()
Line 69: 
Line 70:         List<tblReport> reports = db.tblReports
Line 71:             .Where(rep => DBTablesUsed.Select(x => x.fldReportID).Contains(rep.fldReportID))
Line 72:             .ToList();
 
Line 70 highlighted in red

Comment: @stevee1986 please edit your question and show the details, it's very hard to read from a comment